# Why was this unfriendly/unkind comment flag declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags, comment-flags, offensive

A post that was over 10 years old got bumped recently. I read through the question, answers, and comments (this was probably a mistake).

One of the answers had a string of questionable comments including (what at least reads like) a direct attack on another user:

[image: String of questionable comments including "@***** We can only hope the second step is suicide" (marked). Comment authors redacted.]

I probably could have flagged this particular comment as:

> It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.

But, because I assumed it was not taken or intended to be taken seriously, I decided to flag this comment as:

> It's unfriendly or unkind.

To my surprise, my flag was *declined*.

---

**For what possible reason was my flag declined?**

**Was I incorrect to flag this comment? Did I use the wrong flag type?**

**Or, was the flag declined incorrectly or by mistake?**

---

Contrarily, upon returning to this post, the entire string of comments under that answer have been removed (but my flagging history still shows *declined*).

Incidentally, the commenter also left an insensitive answer that wasn't much good, but at least it wasn't a direct attack on anyone in particular. This answer has also been deleted.

Comment: Probably the moderator used the "decline and delete" option (an actual option).

Comment: The moderator does not remember what was done exactly, but remembers the why :D

Comment: Different times. Context. People joking around. You're missing all of those, utterly.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Quoting your very own comment on the deleted answer by the same user: "This might have been funny back in the day, now it is not."

Comment: Oh, but that's for answer, not comment. And I didn't flag, and won't flag - left the comment for the small chance the author might see and choose to delete.

Answer (score 2):

Well - in a sense It wasn't needed but it wasn't *intended* to be unfriendly or unkind. It was pretty much people being silly.

> One of the answers had a string of questionable comments including (what at least reads like) a direct attack on another user:

"String of questionable comments" was true, hence the comment purge. "a direct attack on another user"... it wasn't.

In broader context it was no longer needed and while there's no 'additional' punishment to a unkind comment by the system, it was probably inaccurate.

As such - well, the comments were brought to our attention, we assessed it, and felt the entire comment thread (and the answer it was under? I forget, but could look it up) wasn't needed and purged it.

I guess a real word equivalent would be friends cussing out each other. Its rude *but* the recipient of said cuss is unlikely to be offended, which is why it survived so long.

It was correct to flag - and it got our attention, and it wasn't a wrong flag to make on its own merits. It *could* have been asking someone to kill themselves, in which case we'd have to take action.

So it wasn't a 'wrong' thing, merely, a different assessment of the 'severity' of the issue.

Comment: I understand they were joking around, but the users making the comments aren't the only people that view them.  It certainly *reads* like a direct attack.  I thought that "It's unfriendly or unkind" *was* the less sever flag.

Comment: No longer needed would have worked. And I'm not averse to a single flag asking us to review all the comments

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Further to the previous comment, I would say that if there's a whole comment thread, I'd much rather have a custom flag telling me that so that I can see the context for myself.